# PHP: What's the difference between static variable inside a for loop and a non-static variable outside the for loop?

Tags: php, static, scope

For example, what's the difference between

```
$foobar = 0
for ($i=0; $i<20; $i++) {
    //do something using $foobar
    $foobar++;
}
```

and

```
for ($i=0; $i<20; $i++) {
    static $foobar = 0
    //do something using $foobar
    $foobar++;
}
```

???

Both of the above examples have different results than from the following:

```
for ($i=0; $i<20; $i++) {
    $foobar = 0
    //do something using $foobar
    $foobar++;
}
```

All three variations have a different outcome. I understand that in the *first* of the three examples the value of the $foobar variable gets larger and larger and that in the *third* example the value of the $foobar variable gets reset during each loop. I'm not sure what's going on with the example using the static $foobar variable. It would seem that the first two examples should behave the same in the portion of the for loop where $foobar is used, but that is not the case for me.

For reference, here's my actual code (the algorithm is not complete yet). I've marked the for() loop that has me thinking about this topic:

```
function combine($charArr, $k) {

    $currentsize = sizeof($charArr);
    static $combs = array();
    static $originalsize = "unset";
    if ($originalsize === "unset") $originalsize = $currentsize;
    static $firstcall = true;

    if ($originalsize >= $k) {

        $comb = '';
        if ($firstcall === true) { 
            for ($i = $originalsize-$k; $i < $originalsize; $i++) {
                $comb .= $charArr[$i];
            }
            $combs[] = $comb; 
            $firstcall = false; 
        }
        if ($currentsize > $k) { 

            $comb = ''; //reset
            for ($i=0; $i<$k; $i++) { 
                $comb .= $charArr[$i];
            }
            $combs[] = $comb;

            //########### THE FOR LOOP IN QUESTION ###########              
            for ($i = $k-1; $i >= 0; $i--) { 
            static $range_adj = 0;
                for ( $j = $i+1; $j < $currentsize-$range_adj; $j++ ) { 
                    if ( !($i == 0 and $j == $currentsize-$range_adj-1) ) { 
                        $comb = substr_replace($comb, $charArr[$j], $i, 1); 
                        $combs[] = $comb;
                    }
                }
                $range_adj++;
            }
            if ($currentsize-1 > $k) { 
                array_splice($charArr, 0, 1); 
                combine($charArr, $k); 
            }
        }
        $output = array_values( $combs );
        unset($combs);
        return $output;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If I remove the `$range_adj` variable from for loop and place it right before the said for loop as a none-`static` variable, then the result of my function is **not** the same. Here's what the modified for loop would look like:

```
            $range_adj = 0;
            for ($i = $k-1; $i >= 0; $i--) { 
                for ( $j = $i+1; $j < $currentsize-$range_adj; $j++ ) { 
                    if ( !($i == 0 and $j == $currentsize-$range_adj-1) ) { 
                        $comb = substr_replace($comb, $charArr[$j], $i, 1); 
                        $combs[] = $comb;
                    }
                }
                $range_adj++;
            }
```

The fact that I get two different outcomes leads me to believe that something is different with each method, because if the two methods produced identical results, then the outcome of my function would be the same in both scenarios, which is not the case when I test these scenarios. Why am I getting two results? Test my function out with both methods of the for loop implemented and you will also get varying results.

For your convenience, here's the original method:

```
            for ($i = $k-1; $i >= 0; $i--) { 
                static $range_adj = 0;
                for ( $j = $i+1; $j < $currentsize-$range_adj; $j++ ) { 
                    if ( !($i == 0 and $j == $currentsize-$range_adj-1) ) { 
                        $comb = substr_replace($comb, $charArr[$j], $i, 1); 
                        $combs[] = $comb;
                    }
                }
                $range_adj++;
            }
```

???

It seems to me that the results should be exactly the same, but they are not. If you run my function, you will notice that you get a different result with each method of the for loop.

Comment: What result do you get in the second one?

Comment: Parse error is the only result one can get from all these codes ;)

Comment: Col. Shrapnel, i'm not getting a parse error! I posted my function above.

Comment: Seriously though. Can someone answer the question? I've updated with as much detail as possible!

Answer (score 2):

The first and second loops appear to do the same thing. This is because, as with any other statically-initialized variable, `static` means you only initialize it once. It retains its value as you try to access it again. You'll find that the static `$foobar` will still exist outside the scope of the loop wherever you declare/initialize it; this is due to the nature of PHP and has nothing to do with the static variable.

The difference is made clear only when you attempt to access `$foobar` before the loop: it won't be declared yet in the second snippet because you only create it within the loop, so you may get an undefined-variable notice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the only part i'm interested in is the part inside the loop where I `//do something using $foobar`. What's the difference there?

Comment: Hey, I understand your answer perfectly, but it doesn't explain my issue. I'm getting differing results when using the two methods described in my question.

Answer (score 1):

`static $foobar = 0;`
initializing once, other execute of `static $foobar = 0` not do anything with $foobar variable

Comment: That's what I thought too... But i get totally different results, which means that something isn't the same. I've added my actual code above. Have a look. Try using that function, then try moving the `static $range_adj` outside the for loop remove the static keyword. Notice the results are different.

Answer (score 0):

Above two prog have same output, but your last prog have variable which is reset during each loop.
when you use "Static" key word for any variable initialization then It retains untill you not destroy it.. or not destroy your program session.

Comment: I disagree. My function (which I've added above to my question) show totally different output depending of which way I try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use static in this fashion to prevent a variable from being **reinitialized** inside a loop.

in the first iteration if the static variable is not initialize then it would create it and keep it within the outer context, on every other iteration PHP Would just skip it as its already been initialized.

Both results prevail the same: http://codepad.org/evilks4R

The reason why it differs in your function is that your function is recursive which means the function combine calls combine from within itself, when taking out the static keyword on the second call of combine, the variable is being **reinitialized** thus making the results differ.

using the static keyword allows you to **pass** the arguments to the second call with there values that was produced in the third value.

here's an example of passing static members to the latter passes of a function call: http://codepad.org/gChjx7Om

if you had done:

```
$foo_bar = 0;
for(.....)
```

this would be within a function so that `$foo_bar` would get reset to **0** every time the function was called, therefore overwriting the last calls calculations.

if you moved the `$foo_bar` outside the function, and then where needed in the function you added:

```
global $foo_bar
```

you would have the same results.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/statickeyword.html

Comment: So you are saying that the first and second examples in my question should technically have the same result, right???... But if you take my function and try either form, you'll get different results. Something must be different between either forms.

Comment: Why would my test case prove otherwise??? I've tried both forms over and over, and keep getting different results.

Comment: I fully understand your example and know exactly what you mean. However, my code is not having the same behavior. Take a look at the end of my question, i've updated it, showing exactly what modifications i'm doing that show two different results.

Comment: You obviously do not understand my update, i explain why this happens, its because its a recursive function, and the results are not being reset each function call.

Comment: Aaaaah, so you're saying that even though it's inside the for loop, it is still static across all the function calls? I see. So everytime that i encounter that for loop, it starts incrementing $range_adj where it left of before.

I get it now. Previously, i thought that since i declared it static inside the for loop, that it would only apply to the for loop. So even if i declare a static variable inside the for loop it will be static across the whole function then, right?

Comment: correct, it applies to the scope, and the for loop is within the function scope, so it will set the variable to the global scope / outermost scope, thus allowing it to be modified over and over again like a global variable.